# Loop through urls in an array and check if a class exists

Tags: javascript

I would like to loop through various urls to check whether a url is down based on an HTML class. So I may have an array including my domains and check which one is down in order to alert me

```
var urls = ['http://www.dummy1.com',  'http://www.dummy2.com' ]
if ($(".underMaintenance")[0]) {  
           alert ("Website Is Down");    
} 
else {  
      //continue looping through the other urls  
}
```

Comment: You cannot use browser based JavaScript access/read the document of an external domain that does not explicitly allow it, if that is not the case you would need to bounce to a server side proxy or do all the work server side.

Comment: How would this work exactly? If a website is down, how can it return a class? If the server is down, you don't get any response. Do you have PHP installed? I would rather use that to check the status

Comment: Thank you @AlexK. for your instant reply. Basically the suitable for me would be a script that would be running continuously with intervals through the urls and while one is browsed and it is down (based on getElementByClassName => .underMaintenance) will then alert me.

Comment: You could do it with javascript  in a browser using a YQL query with xpath to scrape the required element.  If you get nothing, the site is up; if you get a response, the site is down.  Set an interval timer to trigger the queries and increment a counter to change the target URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this through a browser unless you have a ping API endpoint which allows cross domain requests.
Another approach could be sending a request to websites using a back-end language if you want javascript on backend check node.js from your back end. At some point whatever way you choose you will need a back end for this because of restrictions listed [here](http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/cannot.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way about it, but here is a client side javascript solution using a YQL query with xPath to scrape the `inmaintenance' div.  Every 30 seconds (or any other interval, provided it's longer than the query time), it triggers again with the next URL in the array.  Once it gets to the end of the array, it returns to the start.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  check();
});

urls = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
i = 0;

function check() {
  checkQuery = 'select * from html WHERE url = "' + urls[i] + '" AND xpath = "//div[@class = \'inmaintenance\']"';
  checkUrl = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(checkQuery) + '&format=xml';
  $.getJSON(checkUrl + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    if (data.query.length) {
      alert('Server at ' + urls[i] + ' is down');
    }
  }).success(function() {
    i++
    if (i == urls.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      check();
    }, 30000);
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```